# jqgrid 4.6.0 column chooser issues

Tags: jqgrid

**I am using jqGrid  4.6.0. 
Implemented Column chooser feature using the below code. 
I am using**

- **jquery-ui-1.11.1.js**
- **jquery.multi-select.js**
- **jquery-ui.css**
- **multi-select.css**

---

```
$.extend($.ui.multiselect, {
                locale: {
                    addAll: 'Make all visible',
                    removeAll: 'Hidde All',
                    itemsCount: 'Avlialble Columns'
                }
            });
```

---

```
   $.extend(true, $.jgrid.col, {
                width: 500,
                msel_opts: { dividerLocation: 0.5 }
            });
```

---

```
            $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#p" + $grid.attr("id"), {
                caption: "",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                title: "Choose columns",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser',
                         {
                           width: 260,
                           height: 280,
                           classname: "column-chooser",
                           msel_opts: { //multiselect options
                               autoOpen: true,
                               header: true,
                               height: "auto",
                               classes: "column-chooser",
                               beforeclose: function () { return false; } //keep multiselect drop down open  
                           }
                        });
                }
            });
```

**The column chooser popup  is showing up without available columns and make all columns visible options.. 
It just has one option  available i.e., select columns..**

**Can somebody help..**

**thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very suspected where you get `jquery.multi-select.js` and `multi-select.css`. I suppose that you get **wrong files**. jqGrid which you downloads from [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) contains `plugins` subdirectory with `ui.multiselect.js` and `ui.multiselect.css`. So the typical contain of `<head>` of the page where you use jqGrid with `columnChooser` could be the following

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { font-size: 75%; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-4-5-4-column-chooser-bug#p31105) recently where I described some small steps to make "Remove all" and "Add all" working in case of usage the last versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. The modified versions of `ui.multiselect.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` you can download from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect-fixed.js) and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-columnChooser.js).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WorkingColumnChooser.htm) can be used as prototype for the usage of `columnChooser`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a different Multiselect js and css files..

I downloaded the JQGRID 4.6.0 package.. it gave me the ui.multiselect.css and ui.multiselect.js files.. i added them in my project..

now the column chooser popup is showing up with available columns and make all columns visible options.. thank you Oleg.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Small remark: such answer which you posted is *not real answer* on your question. It's better if you post the information as comment to your question or alternatively you can append the text of your question with the text...