# Using columnchooser in jqgrid(one with available column/add column) do I need to add any js or plugin?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I tried using `.columnchooser()`. However I don't get the design. It comes in one column instead of two.

I want like the link below:
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5__.htm

This is my code.

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<h2>Index</h2>
<link href="~/Scripts/local/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/local/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/local/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/local/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/local/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/local/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/local/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/local/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    { id: "10", invdate: "2015-10-01", name: "test", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "20", invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "30", invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "40", invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "50", invdate: "2015-10-31", name: "test5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "60", invdate: "2015-09-06", name: "test6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "70", invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "80", invdate: "2015-10-03", name: "test8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "90", invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "100", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "110", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "120", invdate: "2015-09-10", name: "test12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
                numberTemplate = {
                    formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] }
                };
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name", label: "Client", width: 53 },
                    {
                        name: "invdate", label: "Date", width: 75, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }
                    },
                    { name: "amount", label: "Amount", width: 65, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "tax", label: "Tax", width: 41, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "total", label: "Total", width: 51, template: numberTemplate },
                    {
                        name: "closed", label: "Closed", width: 59, formatter: "checkbox",
                        align: "center", firstsortorder: "desc",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "ship_via", label: "Shipped via", width: 87, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                        editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;DH:DHL", defaultValue: "DH" }
                    }
                ],
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                pager: "#pager",
                sortname: "invdate",
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Usage of columnChooser"
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { add: false, edit: false, del: false }).jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
                caption: "",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                title: "Choose columns",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you forgot to include one from the files: `ui.multiselect.min.css`, `jquery-ui.min.js`, `ui.multiselect.min.js` (or `ui.multiselect.css`, `jquery-ui.js`, `ui.multiselect.js`). The files `ui.multiselect.*` can be found in the `plugins` folder of jqGrid. The files are available on CDN as the part of free jqGrid:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/plugins/ui.multiselect.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/plugins/ui.multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

You can include the files in more safe form too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/plugins/ui.multiselect.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ZiGiMTFP/JPxu5YXtclEjVDGZHbKOP2RBpOke65fQkSTg9yVHjpIBz3heEG6/7ja"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/plugins/ui.multiselect.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-NrAnGBGjwjZspUViA2F5wJAZyC03l65Oaz39yB5Y3YDclQeASNM5luBMgPfDJRKE"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The files will be loaded quickly (using HTTP/2 if the web browser of the client support it) and there will be good cached in the web browsers.

Comment: I am using 4.6. In that case, where can I find the files in NuGet?

Comment: @RustinCohle: [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/4.13.1). Sorry, but I really recommend you to read about the advantages of the usage of CDN, about setting of caching attributes, the usage of HTTP/2 and SPDY which are supported by the most web browsers (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=spdy) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=http2)) and which improve the loading of files additionally. Typical performance advantage of usage HTTP/2 only is 30%. CDN is really strictly recommended. Try to test you site in http://www.webpagetest.org/ and to examine the performance review.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as mentioned here, which @Oleg you tried to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781043/jqgrid-4-6-0-column-chooser-issues Please assist, i have added all files, still i dont get multiselect or two panes for add column/available column. Please help

Comment: @RustinCohle: Do you have the demo which I could see?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont. Where can I create a jqgrid demo easily?

Comment: @ I have tried in this link, not completed. You could add anything to this? http://jsfiddle.net/nagarajputhiyavan/yNw3C/13179/ Thanks

Comment: @RustinCohle: The demo don't contain no javascript files which you use and no javascript code. JSFiddle have "External Resources" on the left side where you can include URLs to all CSS/JS files. Thus if you have problem to use jqGrid you should create **the demo which use the same javascript and css files, which have the problem**. I created two demos for you: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/1/ uses free jqGrid 4.13.1 and  https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/2/, which uses jqGrid 4.6. Both uses `columnChooser` and both have no problem with look of the dialog.

Comment: Thanks. You are the god of jqGrid. It works perfectly in grid. however, when I try in my solution, i dont get the pager icons and +,- icon in columnchooser and some alignment. Any idea?

Comment: @RustinCohle: I can only repeat: **you should post your code**. You made some errors in including of JS/CSS files on in the usage of jqGrid. I can't help you if I don't see **what you do**. If you click on "External Resources" on JSFiddle demos then you will see the order of included JS and CSS files. The order of JS files could be important.

Comment: I have put in the same order. Can I post the code here?

Comment: @RustinCohle: You can any time click on "edit" link below of your question and append the text with additional information. You should just post comment to inform me that you modified the text. The old post http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495 describes how to format the code. The description is long, but it's really very easy. One need just select the lines of the code and click `{}` button to include 4 spaces at the beginning of every line of code.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the code now. Hope its updated ok.

Comment: @RustinCohle: **And what is not working now? Do you verified all paths and that all files are really loaded?** You can include screenshort. You posted fragment of html page. It is fragment inside of the `<body>` or `<head>`? If you include all in the body then you don't need to use `$(document).ready`. But if jqGrid work then columnChooser should work too.

Comment: Some css is missing. I have added the image as well now. Sorry for not doing it properly.

Comment: @RustinCohle: the image looks still strange. You should have some additional compatibility problems with other CSSs, which you use. Do you used jqGrid 4.6 or free jqGrid 4.13.1 in your demo?

Comment: @RustinCohle: I wrote you about the usage of CDN. I recommend you to compare HTTP traffic during loading of your current page with the traffic from CDN. You can start Developer Tools and use Network tab or to use tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). If you would exactly examine the traffic you will see that your side will be not the best choice almost always.

Comment: I have used 4.6 and Yes, some css compatibilty issue, cant figure out. Regarding CDN, my country is still not matured enough to take that option.

Comment: @RustinCohle: I think that you still don't understand how CDN work. I'm sure that you still didn't made HTTP trace and not compared the traffic from your local server and CDN. Your country is Denmark and it has Internet. If you develop the solution for isolated system, which work **without** access of Internet then you should use local web server with all files loaded locally. In all other case the usage of CDN provides better results for every client of your web solution.

Comment: @RustinCohle: About CSS conflict you can try to replace URLs from local jqGrid files to URLs to free jqGrid 4.13.1 and verify whether CSS conflict still exist. I implemented in CSS of free jqGrid many fixes to prevent some standard CSS conflicts.